# Identify type of CD?

Tags: macos, optical-drive, cd-burning

I have a disk with almost no labeling.  I can tell by looking that it's a CD and not a DVD.  I can tell by looking closer which side is which (mfg. part/batch number) and that it is blank (writing makes a band of different appearance).

I can also have my MacBook Pro tell me all those things by putting it in the optical drive.

But is there a non-invasive way for MacOS to tell me whether it's CD-RW or just CD-R?  (ReWritable or Recordable.)

drutil can only tell me the drive's capabilities, unless I try an erase, which may make a CD-R unusable.

Web search for the part number(s) found nothing.

If I try to re-write, I’ll know.  But at that point, it will no longer be usable, and I’ll have to go buy another.

My nephew stopped by and found it by Properties in Windows, but it would be nice to know a MacOS or Darwin method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me, however the system must first recognize the *disc* that's inserted. Otherwise it can't return a *value* for a *property* of a *disc* it hasn't or can't recognize. I have noticed with **RW** *optical media* that it can take some time for the *disc* to be recognized. I have tested with **CD-R**, **CD-RW**, **DVD+R** and **DVD+RW** *optical media* and all report the **Media Type** correctly in **Disk Utility** and **Optical Media Type** correctly using `diskutil`.

You should be able to ascertain the **Media Type** by using the **Info** button in **Disk Utility** after selecting the target *optical device*.

You should be able to ascertain the **Optical Media Type** from the command line in **Terminal** using the following *command*:

```
diskutil info diskN
```

Where `N` in `diskN` is a integer value of the target *optical device*, e.g.: `disk2`

To isolate just the **Optical Media Type** info, use the following *command*:

```
diskutil info diskN | grep 'Optical Media Type'
```

On my system, using the proper number in `diskN`, the output for the *disc* I have currently inserted in the **SuperDrive** is:

```
  Optical Media Type:       CD-R
```

You could also use the following *command* in **Terminal**:

```
system_profiler SPDiscBurningDataType
```

The *output* of which on my system for the *disc* currently inserted is:

```
$ system_profiler SPDiscBurningDataType
Disc Burning:

    HL-DT-ST DVDRW  GX40N:

      Firmware Revision: RQ00
      Interconnect: USB
      Burn Support: Yes (Apple Shipping Drive)
      Cache: 1024 KB
      Reads DVD: Yes
      CD-Write: -R, -RW
      DVD-Write: -R, -R DL, -RW, +R, +R DL, +RW
      Write Strategies: CD-TAO, CD-SAO, CD-Raw, DVD-DAO
      Media:
          Type: CD-R
          Blank: Yes
          Erasable: No
          Overwritable: Yes
          Appendable: Yes
          Write Speeds: 10x, 16x, 24x

$
```

This info is also available in **System Information** via the **GUI** under: **Hardware** > **Disc Burning**

---

**Note:** The information contained herein was tested under OS X 10.8.6 and if using `diskutil info` on the *target optical drive* in a different version of OS X/macOS then you might want to not filter the output through `grep` until sure that `diskutil info` on the *target optical drive* has an `Optical Media Type:` *property* listed, on whatever version is being used, as it does in OS X 10.8.6.

Comment: All of that does work for me, too, except the disk utility info button.